# how does jenkins recognize paths inside a python script?

Tags: python, jenkins, path, onedrive, cloudbees

I have a python script that points to some file names and log files and I have jenkins to run the script, when run locally from my system the code works fine.

The way I access my folders in python:
folder_artifacts_data = 'C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Artifacts/'
path_to_log_file ='C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Logfiles/Logfile.log'

but when I try to run the same using jenkins, I get the following error:

**No such file or directory:**
/opt/jenkins/workspace/confluencetest_scheduled/C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Logfiles/Logfile.log

Now, I tried different file paths and used r-strings

folder_artifacts_data = r'C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Artifacts/'
path_to_log_file =r'C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Logfiles/Logfile.log'

I see that jenkins has accepted the log file, because I see the logs written, but the moment it reaches folder_artifacts_data it throws the error that the file path do not exist.

Could someone help?

**Update**
Now I have added relative paths, like:
folder_artifacts_data0 = 'C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Artifacts/'
folder_artifacts_data = os.path.relpath(folder_artifacts_data0)
path_to_log_file0 ='C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Logfiles/Logfile.log'
path_to_log_file = os.path.relpath(path_to_log_file0)

that outputs paths like:
..............\Rhea\OneDrive -Area\Rhea\Metrics_Configuration\Artifacts

and

..............\Rhea\OneDrive -Area\Rhea\Metrics_Configuration\Logfiles\Logfile.log

this works well in my local, again I get
**No such file or directory:**
/opt/jenkins/workspace/confluencetest_scheduled/C:/Users/Rhea/OneDrive -Area/Rhea/Metrics_Configuration/Logfiles/Logfile.log while running from jenkins.

Comment: Make the paths relative in your script. Your jenkins is a unix-like machine, windows paths won't work there.

Comment: I added relative path but I get the same error, any help? I have been stuck for a week now.